# When are accessor methods for S4 objects called in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

Not quite sure how to ask this question without going into a great deal of detail about my specific programming problem. So, this question is slightly related, but much simpler. I'm trying to understand the procedure R applies when assigning to a slot of an S4 class. I have custom access and assignment functions, "$" and "$<-".

I note two things:

1. the assignment will work when I'm using brackets to subset a specific slot, even though I've not provided any mechanism for doing so. I trust this is merely R's eager embrace of vectorized code. This is fine, but what if I want to enable different subsetting logic? In the toy example below, assume that I'd like to subset based on a match to birthdate.
2. When assigning to a subsetted slot, the "$" accessor will be called. Why is this?

Following is a toy example for illustration. Comment on point 1 and an answer to point 2 are much appreciated.

```
setClass("Person"
     , representation(FirstName = "character"
                      , LastName = "character"
                      , Birthday = "Date")
)

setMethod("$", signature(x = "Person"), function(x, name) {
  print("Just called $ accessor")
  slot(x, name)
})

setMethod("$<-", signature(x = "Person"), function(x, name, value) {
 print("Just called $ assignment")
  slot(x, name) = value
  x
})

objPeople = new("Person"
                , FirstName=c("Ambrose", "Victor", "Jules")
                , LastName=c("Bierce", "Hugo", "Verne")
                , Birthday=seq(as.Date("2001/01/01"), as.Date("2003/12/31"), by="1 year"))

# This assignment will work. When assigning, there will be a call to the "$" accessor function. Why?
objPeople$FirstName[2] = "Joe"

# This assignment will not make a call to the "$" accessor function. Why?
objPeople$FirstName = "Ambroze"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that `[` is just another function, as is `[<-`. So in order to do

```
objPeople$FirstName[2] = "Joe"
```

The `$` is going to run first and return something that the `[<-` can operate on. Something like

```
'$<-'(objPeople, "FirstName", '[<-'( '$'(objPeople, "FirstName"), 2, "Joe"))
```

So in order to subset, it has to extract the first name. But with

```
 objPeople$FirstName = "Ambroze"
```

That's just a

```
'$<-'( objPeople, "FirstName", "Ambroze")
```

so you don't need to call the accessor. You are just directly calling the assignment function.

If you wanted to have a custom subsetter on your class, it would be at the `Person[]` level. If you wanted a custom subsetter on the FirstName slot, you would have to make the FirstName slot a class of it's own where you could re-define the `[` method.

Comment: This makes a great deal of sense. However, if I try to run the line '$<-'( objPeople, "FirstName", "Ambroze"), I get the error "invalid subscript type 'language'". If I try to do the central bit - `[`( `$`(objPeople, "FirstName"), 2) - first, it will return a character string. Feeding this as the name argument to the "$<-" function will throw an error because "Victor" is not the name of a slot.

Comment: @PirateGrunt OK. i've updated the assignment based on something that actually works. I was trying to directly decode `as.list(quote(objPeople$FirstName[2] = "Joe"))` but that appears to be somewhat misleading or maybe isn't the best way to see what's happening.

Comment: Spent a bit of time combing through the "R Internals" documentation and the following statement will execute: objPeople <- `$<-`(objPeople, name="FirstName", value=`[<-`(`$`(objPeople, "FirstName"), 2, value="Joe")). I think it was just a question of using named arguments. Thanks so much for the response. This is all much clearer now.

Comment: I didn't have to use named arguments, so i'm not sure how what we were running was different. It's true that my code above doesn't do the assignment. I left that out. It just returns the value that would be used during reassignment.